# :g showing functions and comments below

Tags: vim

*I'm not sure if this can be accomplished with regex, so here goes and hoping for the best.*

If in vim I do,

```
:g/function
```

I get a list of all function rows.

Now, I'd like that but with comments (!) below until the first non comment row, so I get something like:

```
3 function MyFunction()
4 !This is a comment
5 !This is also a comment
23 function MyOtherFunction()
24 !This is a comment
25 !This is also a comment
```

Something like that possible ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes

---

```
:g/^func/.;/^[^!]/-1 print
```

*Update*

---

An explanation was suggested...so here goes... vi(1) is powerful in part because it is a cursor-addressing extension to Ken Thompson's original line-oriented ed(1) editor. (ed(1) and its spinoff `ex` is still available on Linux after all these years, albeit in clone form like vi itself.) ed and its early-unix siblings were the first programs anywhere to use regular expressions.

Ok, create a file with 26 or so lines, one for each letter of your alphabet and start vi, ed, or ex. (For ed or ex, leave out the : characters.) Try:

```
:1;/m/p
```

The general form of a vi command is: *addr, addr2 commmand*

In my example the command is just `p` for print. addr1 and addr2 are usually a line number or a regular expression using /re/ to search downward or ?re? to search upward. Try `/c/;/g/p` which prompts me to explain: the `;` causes the editor  to switch to the line found by the first address before it evaluates the second address. It doesn't always matter in the default wrapscan mode but if you type `:set nows` (not in ed) then search patterns won't wrap and the difference between `,` and `;` becomes bigger.

The most important line mode command wasn't used in my example but it should be mentioned here: `:s/pattern/replacement/` or `:s/pattern/replacement/g`. This command can of course take addresses so a typical command is `1,$s/old/new/g` The `$` identifies the last line. The default address for most commands is the current line but for the `global` or `g` command it defaults to `1,$` and has the general form

```
addr1, addr2 g /pattern/ any_linemode_command
```

For example, say I'm [**Jeff**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) but I want to blame [**Joel**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) for different types of critical errors in the logs. I need to be stealthy and not change the Jeff's on mere warning lines, so I need:

```
g/critical.*error/s/Jeff/Joel/
```

That will run the substitute command on every line of the file that has the pattern "critical *anything* error" and then just change Jeff to Joel.

So now the answer should be fairly clear. The command works as follows: on every line of the file, check to see if the line begins with /^func/ (func at the beginning of the line) and if it does, start with `.` (the current line) then, resetting the current address to that line (`;`) search for a line that does NOT begin with `!`, and if it's found, subtract one from the line number found (back up slightly to the last actual comment) and then just run the `print` command.

Comment: Wow, that's great. I didn't know that I can combine vi commands like this. Thanks!

Comment: +A ... and once again i'm left stunned and fascinated by the power of line noise in form of regex ;-)

Comment: @DigitalRoss: Can you give a more detailed explanation of every step in your line for the Vim newbies?

Comment: @DigitalRoss: Wow, thanks for the amazing answer. Indeed, you are a master of Vim.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: Great !  the another form of your answer  should be 
:g/^func/.;/^!/-1 p :-)

Comment: @HZ: good point, that was actually in my original answer but got cut out of the update